# Web api not hitting breakpoint and getting 500 internal server error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

We are developing webapi project using visual studio 2012. After build my project it shows Build succeeded. I put breakpoint into my webapi function and I was trying to get my output using fiddler. It's not hitting the breakpoint and getting 500 internal server error in my fiddler output.

Comment: 500 means there is error in cs code.In your case you may be hitting wrong url or with wrong paramter names or types.Post details of error.

Comment: @mairaj Ahmad {"errorCode":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","error":"Internal Server Error","innerErrors":null} this my error message when i tried to execute through fiddler

Comment: Try to browse through browser and than check error in console.

Comment: @MairajAhmad A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in {name}.CentralizedLogger.Framework.dll

Comment: Are you using any logging ?

Comment: yes we are using logging for Success and Error API response

Comment: Put a breakpoint there in start where you initialize this logging,

Comment: Yes break point hitting to log class and getting response as internal  server error

Comment: So you need to debug from start and check where you get exception.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a variable that may contain any string like HTML. You can include attribute of AllowHTML on that specific property.

```
[AllowHtml]
public string OutComes { get; set; }
```